# GEF 5 without Eclipse Platform

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

Is it possible to integrate GEF 5 in a normal Javafx Project?
No Eclipse RCP Platform.
No Eclipse Plugin Project.

Just a simple Java(Fx) Project - adding the dependencies and start it like a normal JavaFx Application?

Comment: Publishing the jars on maven central is covered in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521728 However, you should be able to use the jars that are published on the update site.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing the jars on maven central is covered in http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521728.

However, you should be able to use the jars that are published on the update site.

All GEF code that depends on Eclipse UI is provisioned in separate bundles suffixed with ".ui", i.e. "org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.ui", "org.eclipse.gef.zest.fx.ui", "org.eclipse.gef.fx.ui", etc.

But many parts of the framework are independent from Eclipse, such as:

- Geometry
- Graph
- Layout
- DOT
- etc.